# Start timer that starts the next one after the stop?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

**I've been trying out all the timer or stopwatch options for 2 days and I'm encountering the same problem with all of them.**

My idea is to start a timer via keypress that starts the next one after the time has expired and so on...
I need the whole thing 3 times because each of these timers starts one or more processes and then lets them fade away again in the next timer.

However, I just can't figure out how to adjust the timer or stopwatch so that it makes sense for me, because I have the feeling that the timers in my IF function keep triggering themselves and I would like to prevent that.

It should be possible that timer 1 is only started again by timer 3 and does not start over immediately after it ended itself.

And I still have one question within a question, how do I release my hotkey from the protected area?
or does it make more sense to set a bool that acts as a switch?
Would like to have my hotkey as an on/off function, but so far it only switches on.
And if i press this button maybe 1-2 seconds it repeats but i dont want to repeat thus actions. i need this actions only once after press.

I'm sure someone from the field can be found here who could explain to me immediately what's going wrong with me and I hope so.

**Thanks :-)**

```
    // DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
  
    const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
    const int MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID = 2;
   

    public myFORM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.X);
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.Y);       

    }
   
    // I NEED FOR MY HOTKEY
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
      
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID)
        {

            // STOPWATCH IS CREATED AND STARTED        
            Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch1.Start();

           
                // THAT'S 5 SECONDS
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                // I DON'T NEED THE AREA I JUST NEED TIME STOPPING
                // SO THAT AN ACTION TAKES PLACE
                // HERE I THOUGHT THAT I WILL USE THIS AREA BUT HERE EVERYTHING LOOPS
                // AND MY PROGRAM BEGINS STUCK
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
               
            }

            // STOPWATCH STOP
            stopwatch1.Stop();

            // NOW SOMETHING SHOULD BE DONE
            // AND HERE PROCESSES / THREADS ARE STARTED //
            frmTimer frmTimer = new frmTimer();
            frmTimer.ShowDialog();
            // THEN I WANT A SECOND DIRECTLY
            // STOPWATCH IS CREATED AND STARTED AFTER NO.1 IS FINISHED
            // ONCE THE SECOND STARTS STUCKED IT
            Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch2.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            stopwatch2.Stop();

            Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch3.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            stopwatch3.Stop();
            m_StopThread = true;


        }// THIS WILL CLOSE MY APPLICATION VIA HOTKEY
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION2_HOTKEY_ID)
        {
            this.Close();

        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. For the second part of the question (assuming I understood it correctly), if you want your hotkey to act as an on/off switch, you'd have to implement the logic yourself (add a `bool` as you said). Couple more things: you can sleep the thread for 5000ms, you don't need a `for` loop. You can also reset your stopwatch, you don't need to make 3 different objects (unless you need them)

Comment: right, for my on/off problem did i have set already a bool, but my problem with the for loop is that i need my thread to run 5 seconds and not only sleep 5seonds. i dont know how to reset my timer after he is done. :/ did you have a example?

Comment: There are `.Reset()` and `.Restart()` methods for [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0#methods). But could you explain the use-case for your code, i.e. why are 5 seconds so important for a method to run?

Comment: 5 seconds are only for test. in this 5 seconds i know if the other threads are starts or not. normally does a timer take about 10 minutes. but i wont wait 10 minutes only for test :)

Comment: How does one make a process "fade away" ?

Comment: This is one of my problems, maybe a Task delay can help me, but i need this inclusive a Timer function. I want to run a Timer, this timer starts a Thread and after the time is gone, the Threads sleeps or have Task Delay. and then it all repeats automatically

Comment: You don't need to announce in the title and in bold at the top of the question and in bold at the top of your answer that you've found a solution to your problem and posted it as an answer.  You can just...post your solution as an answer; Stack Overflow's user interface as well as just the nature of how the site works will make all of that clear to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

**[ANSWER FOR OTHER PEOPLE, MAYBE IT HELPS OTHER TOO]**

***i started again from zero to make it clear and this is my result.***

**Explain:**
My StartButton starts a Thread, this Thread have a Stopwatch, if this time is over then flag is set to true and the next Thread is starting. At the same time sets the Stopwatch a other Thread with flag to false and so on....

After the last Stopwatch is stopped is my StartButton is clickable again. And all Threads ready for the next round.

[Optional/FASTSTOP]The StopButton sets *all bool* to false and stops the Threads.

```
private bool _startbutton = false;
private bool _stopbutton = false;
private bool _entTHREAD = false;
private bool _acTHREAD = false;
private bool _seTHREAD = false;
private bool _fiTHREAD = false;
private bool _spTHREAD = false;
private bool _enTHREAD = false;
private bool _en2THREAD = false;


       private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if(!_startbutton)
        {
            _startbutton = true;

            frmTimer frmTimer = new frmTimer();
            frmTimer.Show();
            new Thread(Stopwatch).Start();

        }      
    }
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_stopbutton)
        {
            _stopbutton = true;

            _entTHREAD = false;
            _acTHREAD = false;
            _seTHREAD = false;
            _fiTHREAD = false;
            _spTHREAD = false;
            _enTHREAD = false;
            _en2THREAD = false;
        }
    }
void Stopwatch()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    _entTHREAD = true;
    new Thread(entTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(Stopwatch2).Start();

}

void Stopwatch2()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch2.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch2.Stop();
    _entTHREAD = false;
    _acTHREAD = true;
    new Thread(acTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(Stopwatch3).Start();

}
void Stopwatch3()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch3.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch3.Stop();
    _acTHREAD = false;
    _seTHREAD = true;
    _fiTHREAD = true;
    _spTHREAD = true;

    new Thread(seTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(fiTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(spTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(Stopwatch4).Start();

}
void Stopwatch4()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch4 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch4.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch4.Stop();
    _seTHREAD = false;
    _fiTHREAD = false;
    _spTHREAD = false;
    _enTHREAD = true;
   new Thread(enTHREAD).Start();
    new Thread(Stopwatch5).Start();
}
void Stopwatch5()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch5 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch5.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch5.Stop();
    _enTHREAD = false;
    _en2THREAD = true;
    new Thread(en2THREAD).Start();
    new Thread(Stopwatch6).Start();

}
void Stopwatch6()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch6 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch6.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    stopwatch6.Stop();
    _en2THREAD = false;
    _startbutton = false;

}
```

Comment: I can't tell what function the stopwatch provides. It seems to me that if you removed it, the code would have exactly the same.

Comment: Also you can't pass a boolean to a Thread constructor. As written, this code will not compile.

Comment: It works. so my program is already compiled. just try it.

Comment: A `Stopwatch` doesn't count _down_ to `0` but, while `IsRunning` is `true`, counts _up_ infinitely.  It's used for measuring, not limiting, the time an action takes.  Though you _could_ implement a timer with one, at no point have you actually configured any of these `Stopwatch` instances with how long they should run because the class provides no such support for that; it's calling `Sleep()` in `for` loops that is actually providing your "timer" functionality.  Also, `new Thread(enTHREAD).Start();` will not compile because `enTHREAD` is not defined; `_enTHREAD`, however, is a `bool` variable.

Comment: You also have two `bool` fields both named `_enTHREAD`, so this is clearly not the actual code you've compiled and run.

Comment: @ShiiikK I missed the underscores.

Comment: maybe you look closer :P _enTHREAD and _en2THREAD are not the same

Comment: np but your right with one thing. this is really not my original code. I shortened the names for StackOverflow. Using this program is unethical and in order not to offend anyone i have shortened the boolean names

Comment: @siride was right the first time in stating that [this code will not compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yIzIE0), though it's actually because of numerous errors due to duplicate or undefined identifiers; "fix" all those by adding in the missing underscores and _then_ the problem becomes a matter of trying to pass `bool`s as `ThreadStart`s.  Though there's nothing wrong with posting anonymized code, especially in an answer that code still should compile.  It's also highly recommended for that code to be 1) good code that 2) actually works and 3) for the reasons it claims to.

Comment: Thanks post is edited. About the bools to flag ThreadStarts.. did you know a cleaner way? I heared from someone, i should use async TASKS, but for my script it is important to run one by one and not async to ya. On each Thread i have a WHILE and this have to be continued until time is over and only then is it the next THREADS turn. What did you think about that?

Comment: If you are running things in sequence, you either need no threads (except the main thread that already exists), or exactly one thread aside from the main thread that can run the tasks in sequence. I'd do the latter approach only if the main thread is a UI thread that can't be blocked by processing, which seems to be the case.

Comment: This still won't compile! You fixed the duplicate field names but not the 7 errors from trying to pass an undefined-identifier-named-similar-to-a-`bool` as a `ThreadStart`. What are you even trying to do there? Are those supposed to be `if` statements? "On each Thread i have a WHILE and ... " — Why is that code not shown anywhere on this page? It is a waste of everyone's time asking for feedback when all you'll provide is incomplete code with unclear purpose and inadequate description that doesn't compile, anyway. This "answer" really should be edited into the question, then follow [reprex].